# Clarification on the insert function of panda DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

I have a question, I am trying to get more familiar with python and pandas and I was wondering why this does not work:

list_features_countries = [features_AU, features_CA, features_UK, features_US, features_JP, features_DE, features_SW]

```
for x in list_features_countries:

    x = x.drop(columns=x.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
    x = x.insert(0,'time_period', Eco_AU['time_period'])
```

(It gave the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert')

But, this does work:

list_features_countries = [features_AU, features_CA, features_UK, features_US, features_JP, features_DE, features_SW]

```
 for x in list_features_countries
     x = x.drop(columns=x.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)

 for x in list_features_countries: 
     x = x.insert(0,'time_period', Eco_AU['time_period'])
```

So basically I tried to remove the first column of every dataframe in the list and then add a column of another dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first variant is the parameter `inplace=True`.
This means that the existing dataframe (x) is changed in place and the call `x.drop(... inplace=True)` returns None.
So x is assigned None at this point, which leads to the error message in the next step.

The solution would be either to remove the `inplace=True` parameter so that the `x.drop(...)` function returns the edited dataframe:

```
x = x.drop(columns=x.columns[0], axis=1)
x = x.insert(0,'time_period', Eco_AU['time_period'])
```

or to remove the assignment:

```
x.drop(columns=x.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
x = x.insert(0,'time_period', Eco_AU['time_period'])
```